# TabPy Tableau Convert Dimension where each row is in Hex to ASCII with calculated field with Python

Tags: python, hex, ascii, tableau-api, tabpy

I have a Dimension in Tableau where each row is in Hex (Tableau Datatype is string, but these values are actually hex). I want to convert this dimension (each row) into ASCII with Python Code (TabPy (calculated Field)). Does anyone know how to do that? :D

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
SCRIPT_STR("
result=[]
for a in (_arg1):
   if a == None:
      result.append('')
   else:
      result.append(bytes.fromhex(a).decode('utf-8'))
return result

",ATTR([Your Dimension]))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).